# Acess control allow origin header is present on the request resource. Origin null is therefore not allowed acess

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, cross-section

I'm trying to use the openlayers vector class. And the error occurred:

```
Acess control allow origin header is present on the request resource. Origin null is therefore not allowed acess
```

I've put tileOptions and yet the error persists. 
My GeoJSON file is in the www root of geoserver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>


 var map;

 function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});     
    //Create a Format object
    var vector_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({});

    //Create a Protocol
    var vector_protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url:'stops.geojson',
        format: vector_format
    });

    //Create Strategy
    var vector_strategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()];

    //Create a vector layer that contains a Format, Protocol, and Strategy class
    vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        'More Advanced Vector Layer',
        {
            protocol: vector_protocol,
            strategies: vector_strategies
        },

     {"tileOptions": {
         "crossOriginKeyword": null
     }

    });

    map.addLayer(vector_layer);


  if(!map.getCenter()){
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
 }
 }


 </script>
</head>

<body onload='init();'> <!-- Chama a função js init() --> 

<!--Elemento HTML onde o mapa é exibido -->
 <div id='map_element' style='width: 500px; height: 500px;'>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that the exact error (looks like at least some typos)? Can you check if it really starts with ```No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'...```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file ://...... No 'Acess control allow origin' header is present on the request resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed acess

Comment: Please update the question with the exact error message. (e.g. Does it really say Acess or Access?)